Why are my LEDs not behaving properly upon wiring them to the outputs of my 74LS47 decoder?
Everything works properly in terms of logistics. I wired the inputs as LLHL following the truth table of the datasheet of the decoder (inputs are wired properly). Then I wired left LED to g and right LED to f. If I wiggle the wires, left LED flickers but right LED isn’t flashing at all (1st picture).
If I take off right LED, the left LED turns on (4th picture).
The second and third pictures are snippets of the truth table and a diagram of the 74LS47 decoder (BCD to 7 segment for common anode displays).

Pictures: https://imgur.com/a/O1noN78

Hi, Can you please post the pictures to the website because some users have firewalls (including the computer that I have) that block websites.

I was just typing the same thing Jadon said, I had to disable my firewall in order to see the images. In the question editor there is a button at the top for adding images. Also when taking pictures of a breadboard try to get the whole thing, you appear to have a disconnected power bus but I can't see one end of the board where you may have it connected.

And to make things worse, I can't disable my firewall as this computer (one that I am using right now) is controlled by an admin.

I've inlined one of your images. Please to screenshots of the others instead of photographing the screen and upload them in the same manner.

This can be reopened if you provide the required information and then flag to reopen. Please see various user comments. A circuit diagram will help and a full version of the board and a description of what is connected to each of the rails is required.

Possibly unintuitive answers: 1. A damaged prototyping board.  2. An LED having a loose bond wire. 3. Oxidized resistor leads, LED leads, chip leads, power leads, etc.4. Having one bus with an intermittent connection. You can take this chip, glue it upside down, and bend down the leads, dead-bug style. Then use only soldered connections. This removes intermittent connections from the problem space, leaving: 1. LED bond wire. 2. Damaged chip (ESD?). 3. Power supply flaky. That's it. You can switch out other LEDs to eliminate Bond wire problem. Dead end? Try praying, which often works for me.

I now often use steel wool on my resistor leads to ensure they're clean. I like to leave my TH resistor leads uncut. Also, I have found white LEDs to generally have fewer problems and be more robust, hearty.

I can see several possible problems.
Pin 1 (A1) is connected to the lower positive bus, but I don't see any other connection to that bus, unless you've connected it at the end that we can't see in the photo. Same for the negative bus, I don't see where it's connected.
The LEDs are connect to the upper negative bus through resistors. The 74LS47 has open collector outputs, which means the outputs are pulled low when active (notice they are labeled \$\overline a\$ through \$\overline g\$), so the LEDs should be connected to a positive supply through resistors. Since you don't show or tell us how the power is connected we can't tell if you have that bus connected to positive or negative.
I would double check all of the wiring and if it still doesn't work you'll need to post better images and a schematic.

I believe the LLHL is correct according to the pinout of the IC. In the Fairchild datasheet, pin 1 is A1, pin 2 is A2, pin 6 is A3, and pin 7 is A0.

@SteKulov Correct you are.
